# Why "yticks" is not working with my Python Code? With Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Thanks for answers,
FALSE:
plt.yticks=(np.arange(0, 10))
TRUE:
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,10))

---

I tried to set "yticks" with my Python Code.
However, not working.

Not only "yticks", but also "xticks".

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
y=[2, 6, 9, 8, 4, 5, 8, 0, 2, 7]

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.yticks=(np.arange(0, 10))
```

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGow1.png)

I wrote "ax1.yticks=(np.arange(0, 10))"
But it shows [0.0,2.5,5.0,7.5] or [0,2,4,6,8].

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have the plt interactive mode on by default, I think you should probably set the axis before plotting:

```
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 10))
plt.plot(x,y)
```

... and also remove the `=` that I had not noticed before...

Answer (score 0):

`yticks`is a function:

```
print(plt.yticks)
```

> function yticks at 0x0000026FE714FEA0

You are overwriting the function `yticks` with the assign operator `=` instead of calling it. 
Try (without equality sign):

```
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,10))
```